# Google Sheets API v4 - How to get last modification date?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets

I'm using old API v3 method, but it works only with old tables and will be deprecated eventually.

Anyone knows the way to get table modification date from new v4 API?

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Check the documentation try and come back and let us know if you have any problems.

Comment: What did you try to do? What does documentation say?

Comment: Docs says nothing, i searched all methods, but no one returns last modification date of the sheet. In old api v3 i can GET [http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/${sheetId}/od6/public/values?alt=json](http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/${sheetId}/od6/public/values?alt=json) and receive last update date.

Comment: Were you able to find anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and found this question before I found an answer, so here's the answer for future searchers (and yourself if you somehow still need it)

At the time of writing, the Sheets API itself doesn't have access to simple file metadata, but the Drive API does. It took me way too long to find the example on [this Drive docs page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#node.js) explaining how to use the fields parameter - which is required to get any date data for files in general (docs, sheets, etc). Here's an abridged version of the linked code example in TypeScript:

```js
async function authAndGetGoogleSheetsWithDates() {
  // setup
  const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
  const {google} = require('googleapis');
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
  });
  const service = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

  try {
    // Here's the actual bit of interest, specifically the "fields" value
    const res = await service.files.list({
      q: "mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' and trashed = false",
      fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, modifiedDate, createdDate)',
      spaces: 'drive',
    });
    res.data.files.forEach(function(file) {
      console.log('Found file:', file.name, file.id);
    });
    return res.data.files;
  } catch (err) {
    // 
  }
}
```

From here, accessing those properties might look like this

```js
files = authAndGetDriveFiles();
files.forEach((file) => {
  const date = new Date(file.modifiedTime);
  console.log(`File ${file.name} was last changed at ${date}`)
});
```